# Issues about "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64"

Tags: ios

There are a few questions about this error message in Stackoverflow. The solution is to change the **Architectures** to "$(ARCHS_STANDARD)". But I'm using a third party library which has only 32 bits build. So I can only use $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) in my case. I have a few questions:

1. Is this allowed by Apple to still use $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)? Will it be rejected?
2. I got "using an empty LLDB target which can cause slow memory reads from remote devices". Any way to solve this?

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existing apps can be submitted without 64bit support until June, but new apps must support 64bit.

Comment: That means if my third party 32 bits library must be upgraded to 64 bits after June. Am I right?